# OpenCV 3 Python 3.5 Anaconda

Tags: python, ffmpeg, anaconda, opencv3.0, python-3.5

I  have tried installing opencv 3 in anaconda virtual env.I used the following binstar package..

```
conda

source activate (envname)

conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv

conda list
```

**cv__version__ also  gives the correct output 3.1.0**

This is my first sample code

```
 import numpy as np
 import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

  while(True):
# Capture frame-by-frame
ret, frame = cap.read()

# Our operations on the frame come here
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

# When everything done, release the capture
 cap.release()
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get the following errors on run ./fp.py: line 1: import: command not found
./fp.py: line 2: import: command not found
./fp.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./fp.py: line 4:`cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)'

Whenever i used import video as video, i get errors saying error:video module not found.I think this has something todo with ffmpeg not being present in the binstar package i downloaded.

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. There is no way we can answer your question as it is.

Comment: does the edit help

Comment: Please check again this paragraph: `Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.`

Comment: done! i have added the sample code used as well

Answer (score -1):

Generally, you should run " python  fp.py "  instead of ./fp.py.

The . command will run a bash-script(xxx.sh) in current shell, and python xxx.py will run the python file.

Enjoy !

Comment: Whenver i used import video as video, i get error video module not found.This was the fault regarding the ffmpeg thing not being there there in the binstar package i downloaded!